# Change date format to yyyy-MM-dd in parameter in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am using a date parameter of the java.sql.Date class in Jaspersoft studio 6.19, the problem is that the date is presented to me as 1/3/22 and I need it in the form 2022-03-01, any way to do this? since then I have to upload the report to jasperserver (community version) and I can't do this (Yes, it can, but it changes the format for all reports and I only need it for a few).

[image]

Comment: What is your question? How to change the mask for calendar input control at JasperReports Serverr? Or how to format parameter's value?

Comment: Nope, change it for jaspersoft studio, in jasperserver that doesn't work for me because it changes everything, while if I change it in jaspersoft studio I can adjust it to what I need.

Comment: What is reason to change the mask of input control at Studio, not at the report? The JSS is just a gui editor - the tool for the developer, not the interface for end-user.

Comment: Yes, I have just realized that this is not possible, anyway thanks for confirming it